# Working with Arrays LOD

Tags: game-engine, modifiers

I was wondering if the LOD feature is working on top of an array modifier.

Comment: Could you explain your scene in a little more detail? From what I can tell, you have an object with LOD, but also with an array modifier. Does the object's LOD work if you disable the array modifier?

Comment: yes, i had no problem with LOD, but I'm asking this as I can't acces my computer to test if on a big scale array it works or if i have to apply the array and split the meshes. I want to create a land from tileable patches.

Comment: Instead of using an array modifier, I'd just use Alt+D to duplicate the object but keep the same mesh data.

Comment: Well the purpose was using the "merge" option of the arrays as it allows to set up a huge area with 0 offset in between my (tileable) patches of terrain, on top of it I can also add a displace modifier. Anyway I'll try this as soon as I get my workstation back because now I'm on an eeepc (700mghz, 1G, no graphic cards) and cannot use newer versions than 2.66 where LOD feature's not yet implemented.

Answer (score 1):

I once tried to setup terrain from a heightmap. It would auto-generate terrain tiles using displace, it would create different LOD levels with the decimate modifier and a vertex group (so the edges still lined up).
It worked great in the viewport, but didn't work in the game engine.

Modifiers are a bit strange in the GE. Sometimes they appear correctly, but when adding objects you get CPU spikes (there was one case I worked on where modifiers caused a drop from 60FPS to 20, but that was on lots and lots of objects). Other times they simply don't work. LOD seems to make modifiers in the GE not work.